# Generating Forms for Lumen

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, lumen

I'm searching a pretty way to get **HTML forms** with the **Lumen** framework.

I've tried **Former** (http://formers.github.io/former/), but even with the **4.0 branch**, I couldn't get it working at all (tell me if you could and I'm wrong) with Lumen (some Class path.config does not exist - did you try and get the same?).

How can I get forms generated with that framework (I usually use Bootstrap forms)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This issue must be fixed by the package's developer or you can send try and fork their project if you want.

There are only a few packages supporting the [Lumen framework](http://lumen.laravel.com) for now.

---

**Note:**
I've just opened an issue asking for [Lumen compatibility](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub/issues/10) linking to the [following conversation](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel/issues/67#issuecomment-94948061).

> - A simple solution would be to not use helpers that are only defined by illuminate/foundation. Then this would allow usage in any app that uses laravel components. I'd always recommend that. :)
>
> - @GrahamCampbell What's a better way to get the config path?
>
> - Resolve 'path.config' from the ioc container.